# Eclipse - Java - Плагин подсветки определенного паттерна кода

Tags: eclipse, плагин

Всем привет.

Существует ли простой плагин для Eclipse, постоянно выделяющий определенный текст в коде (без использования Search и проч.)?

Например, рисовать красный background для строки abc = 1; или применять bold и т.д:

abc = 0; // не выделен

doAnalyze(abc);

**abc = 1;** // выделен

doAnalyze(abc);

Ищу довольно давно, ничего похожего не видел. Спасибо заранее.